# OpenCV installation on CLion using CMake | Undefined reference build error

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, clion

For a school project, i want to install OpenCV on CLion.

I downloaded the OpenCV installer for windows and extracted OpenCV on my C: disk.
I added the path to the OpenCV lib and bin folders to my system environment variables.

Here is my CMakeList.txt file :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(poumons VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_executable(poumons main.cpp)

target_link_libraries( poumons ${OpenCV_LIBS})

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

Here is the output of the CMake build :

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2022.2.4\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2022.2.4/bin/ninja/win/ninja.exe" -G Ninja -S C:\Users\axell\CLionProjects\poumons -B C:\Users\axell\CLionProjects\poumons\cmake-build-debug
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/axell/CLionProjects/poumons/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

Here is the source file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    /*Mat image;
    image = imread("./moi.png");
    imshow("fenetre" ,image);
    waitKey(0);*/
    cv::Mat image2;
    return 0;
}
```

but when I build the project, here is the output:

```
====================[ Build | all | Debug ]=====================================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2022.2.4\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\axell\CLionProjects\poumons\cmake-build-debug --target all -j 6
[1/1] Linking CXX executable poumons.exe
FAILED: poumons.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\PROGRA~1\JETBRA~1\CLION2~1.4\bin\mingw\bin\G__~1.EXE -g  CMakeFiles/poumons.dir/main.cpp.obj -o poumons.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libpoumons.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  C:/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world460d.lib  C:/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world460d.lib  C:/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world460d.lib  C:/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world460d.lib  C:/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world460d.lib  C:/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world460d.lib  C:/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world460d.lib  C:/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world460d.lib  C:/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world460d.lib  C:/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world460d.lib  C:/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world460d.lib  C:/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world460d.lib  C:/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world460d.lib  C:/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world460d.lib  C:/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world460d.lib  C:/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib/opencv_world460d.lib  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2022.2.4\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/poumons.dir/main.cpp.obj:C:/Users/axell/CLionProjects/poumons/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat()'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2022.2.4\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/poumons.dir/main.cpp.obj: in function `main':
C:/Users/axell/CLionProjects/poumons/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I tried to use Visual Studio Code to see if my OpenCV is correctly installed, and it worked perfectly, but not on CLion.

I don't know what I missed or did wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: if nobody forces you do write C++ code, just go with Python. OpenCV is a lot easier to use from Python. -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/getting-help.html https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200363649-CLion

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. For the solution, it was enough for me to edit the clion build settings. Which build you are using in visual studio code, you should edit your clion settings like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woEW3.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).